# How to save <ipython.core.display.image object>

Tags: python, ipython, display

I have png data that I can display via IPython.core.display.Image

Code example:

```
class GoogleMap(object):
    """Class that stores a PNG image"""
    def __init__(self, lat, long, satellite=True,
                    zoom=10, size=(400,400), sensor=False):
        """Define the map parameters"""
        base="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?"
        params=dict(
                sensor= str(sensor).lower(),
                zoom= zoom,
                size= "x".join(map(str, size)),
                center= ",".join(map(str, (lat, long) )),
                style="feature:all|element:labels|visibility:off"
                )

        if satellite:
            params["maptype"]="satellite"

        # Fetch our PNG image data
        self.image = requests.get(base, params=params).content
        
        
import IPython
IPython.core.display.Image(GoogleMap(51.0, 0.0).image)
```

Result:

[image: result]

How can I save this picture into a png file.

Im actually interested in putting this into a loop, so 1 png file has like 3 pictures continuously.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is use Python's standard file-writing behavior:

```
img = GoogleMap(51.0, 0.0)
with open("GoogleMap.png", "wb") as png:
    png.write(img.image)
```

Here's a very simple way of accessing the three lat/long pairs you want:

```
places = [GoogleMap(51.0, 0.0), GoogleMap(60.2, 5.2), GoogleMap(71.9, 8.9)]
for position, place in enumerate(places):
    with open("place_{}.png".format(position), "wb") as png:
        png.write(place.image)
```

I'll leave it up to you to write a function that takes arbitrary latitude/longitude pairs and saves images of them.

Comment: Thanks! How do I write in a loop? for ex I want 3 pictures of (51.0, 0.0), (60.2, 5.2), (71.9, 8.9) in 1 png file

Comment: You won't be able to save three images to a single PNG file without using something like [Pillow](https://python-pillow.org/) to create a single canvas and place them on it first.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, but shoudnt it be with open("place_{0}.png".format(position), "wb") as png

Comment: @M_D nope. If you look at the [`str.format()` format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) you'll see that `{}` braces in the format string are substituted implicitly as long as the number of arguments match the number of paired braces. You *can* add explicit place marks if you want, especially if the arguments will be repeated or are out of order, but they're not necessary.

Comment: what i mean is in your answer you forget .format(position). We can use both "place_{0}.png".format(position) or "place_{}.png".format(position). But i got it to what i want, so I really appreciate your help!

Comment: When writing to file, shouldn't `GoogleMap.image` be `GoogleMap.image.data`?